# Multi input/output with autoencoder type network with feedback layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

Hi I have the following multi input `x = [k], [a], [u1, u2, u3,..., uN]`. and outputs `y = [b], [w1, w2, w3, ..., wN]`. where:

1. k, N are integers. k<N
2. `a, b` are vectors of same dimensions.
3. `u1, u2, ..., uN, w1, w2, w3,..., wN` are of same dimensions.

Suppose `NN` represent my neural network, constructed as follows:

```
out_1 = encoder(a)
out_2 = encoder(ui)
out_3 = some_Dense_network(out_1, out_2)
b = decoder(out_3)
w = decoder(out_3)
```

It essentially has two inputs and two outputs

```
NN= Model(inputs=[a, u], outputs = [b, w])
```

I am trying to compute my outputs as follows in a feedback loop

```
u =[u1, u2, u3,..., uN]
w = [w1, w2, w3, ..., wN]
for i in range(k):
    a, w[i] = NN(a, u[k]) # this is the feedback loop 
b = a # is the final output
```

I wrote the code with multiple inputs and outputs (NN) in Tensorflow.

After this I tried the following:

```
final_model = Model(inputs=[k, a, u1, u2,.., uN], outputs = [b, w1, w2,...,wN])
```

This did not work.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? can you try simplifying the above problem?.

Comment: @V.M let say we have two inputs k, u to the neural network. I need to use k as an iterator ( for j in range(k))... It is resulting in an error

Comment: NN(a, u[k]) doesnt seem to be a variable in `i` the loop should produce the same output to `w[I]` for every I?.